# Retrieving forgotten serial number for adobe CS4

Tags: license-key, adobe-cs4, software-activation

I have Adobe CS4 installed on my iMac, but I forgot where I wrote down the serial number. I want to move it to a different computer in the future, but I would need the serial number to reinstall in. Is there some way I can get it? The current install is activated and working fine on my iMac, but how do I get the serial number that I activated it with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you bought the product from a physical store and have a CD you can call up adobe and be able to send in some physical proof that you do in fact have a licensed copy of CS4.  Otherwise if you bought it online then you should still have the email with the install/serial, and your adobe account should show that you bought it.

Simply put, if it's a legit copy (I'm not saying it isn't, it most likely is) then just contacting adobe should be the quickest way to get this resolved.

Comment: It is a legitimate (student) copy. I read somewhere that if you deactivate, uninstall and reinstall it on the same computer, it will remember the serial number, so it will automatically fill out. Is this true? Because in the deactivation window, there is a checkbox for erasing the serial number or leaving it.